# Validacion de 2 input hora mayor antes de enviar

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, validación, datetime

Necesito realizar la validación de 2 inputs que son para elegir una hora inicial y una hora final (formato 24H) y que se validen en tiempo real, para que avise al usuario antes de apretar el botón "guardar".

Esta es la idea, primero validar que la fecha_inicial y fecha_final sean iguales, si es así validar la hora, mi idea es algo similar al pattern, tengo entendido que se puede utilizar un mensaje personalizado con CustomValidity.

```
if (input_Fecha_inicio === input_Fecha_final){
    if (input_Hora_inicial > input_Hora_final){
        "hora final debe ser mayor a la hora inicial"
    }   
}
```

utilizo Bootstrap 4 y TempusDominus para la manipulación de fechas y hora.

este es mi formulario

```
<form id="create_event_frm" data-target="create_event_frm" action="{{route('etable')}}"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  @csrf
  <div class="row"> <!-- SECCION DE INPUT TITULO Y TOGGLET'S -->
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input  type="text" name="event_title" id="event_title" required maxlength="60" class="form-control" placeholder="Titulo del evento">
        <input  type="hidden" id="set_start_time_data" value="No" />  
        <input  type="hidden" id="set_end_time_data" value="No" />  
        <input  type="hidden" name="set_end_date_data" id="set_end_date_data" value="No" />  
      </div> 
    </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row"> <!-- SECCION FECHA INICIO / HORA INICIO / TOGGLET -->

      <div class="col-5 col-xl-5">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group date" name="event_start_date" id="event_start_date" data-target-input="nearest">
                <input type="text" pattern="(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d" placeholder="Fecha de inicio" name="event_start_date" required id="event_start_date" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#event_start_date" />
                <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#event_start_date" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                    <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 col-xl-5" id="event_start_time_area" style="display: none">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group date" id="event_start_time" data-target-input="nearest">
                <input type="text" name="event_start_time" id="event_start_time" value="00:00" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#event_start_time" placeholder="Hora de inicio"/>
                <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#event_start_time" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                    <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-clock"></i></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-3 col-xl-2" >
        <div id="start_time_toggle">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-md" title="Añadir hora de inicio" onclick="add_start_time()"> 
            <i class="text-success fa fa-plus"></i>
            <i class="text-success fa fa-clock"></i>
          </button>  
        </div>
      </div>   
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row" id="end_date_area" style="display: none"> <!-- SECCION FECHA TERMINO / HORA TERMINO / TOGGLET --> 
      <div class="col-5 col-xl-5">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group date" name="event_end_date" id="event_end_date" data-target-input="nearest">
                <input type="text" pattern="(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d" name="event_end_date" id="event_end_date" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#event_end_date" placeholder="Fecha de termino"/>
                <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#event_end_date" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                    <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 col-xl-5" id="event_end_time_area" style="display: none">
        <div class="input-group date" id="event_end_time" data-target-input="nearest">
                <input type="text" name="event_end_time" id="event_end_time" value="23:59" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#event_end_time" placeholder="Hora de termino"/>
                <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#event_end_time" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                    <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-clock"></i></div>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-3 col-xl-2">
        <div id="end_time_toggle">
          <button type="button"  class="btn btn-md" title="Añadir hora de termino" onclick="add_end_time()"> 
          <i class="text-success fa fa-plus"></i>
          <i class="text-success fa fa-clock"></i>
          </button>  
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row"> <!-- BOTONES AGREGAR Y ELIMINAR FECHA DE TERMINO -->
    <div class="col-3 col-xl-2">
      <div id="end_date_toggle">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="add_end_date()" style="width: 117px" ><i class="text-success fa fa-plus"></i> Fecha fin </button>
      </div>
      <div style="display: none" id="btn-eliminar">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="remove_end_date()" style="width: 117px" > <i class="text-danger fa fa-times"></i> Eliminar </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="section row"> <!-- DESCRIPCION -->
      <div class="col-xl-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea class="form-control" id="event_description" name="event_description" placeholder="Descripcion" ></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between col-12"> <!-- FOOTER DEL MODAL -->
    <button type="button" id="btnCerrar" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="reset_config()">Cerrar</button>
    <button type="submit" id="create_event_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He hecho un pequeño ejemplo que espero que te sirva.

Lo que hago es lo siguiente. Obtengo el valor de los distintos inputs y, como para usar `TempusDominus` has de incluir `momentjs` aprovecho y los convierto en objetos de moment.

Los comparo con el método `isBefore()` después de descubrir si alguno de los inputs está vacío. Y lanzo el error si `isBefore()` es `true`.

Añado un `eventListener()` al evento `change` de los datetimepicker y listo.

```js
jQuery('#init-date, #end-date').datetimepicker({
  format: 'hh:mm'
});

jQuery('#init-date, #end-date').on('change.datetimepicker', () => {
  const initDateValue = moment(jQuery('#init-date').data('date'), 'hh:mm');
  const endDateValue = moment(jQuery('#end-date').data('date'), 'hh:mm');
  
  if(!initDateValue.isValid() || !endDateValue.isValid()) return;
  
  if(endDateValue.isBefore(initDateValue)) {
    alert('La fecha fin no puede ser anterior a la fecha inicio');  
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.0-alpha14/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.0-alpha14/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>



<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Init Date</label>
                <div class="input-group date" id="init-date" data-target-input="nearest">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#init-date"/>
                    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#init-date" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>End Date</label>
                <div class="input-group date" id="end-date" data-target-input="nearest">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#end-date"/>
                    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#end-date" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, efectivamente, es parte de lo que necesito, ya que primero debo validar que ` fecha_inicial === fecha_final `. lo otro, la respuesta del jQuery, en vez de un alert, puede ser una notificación similar a la de pattern? (como la de required).

Comment: Claro, en el ejemplo solo te he puesto el caso de la hora, pero al final la comprobación de la hora es básicamente la misma. Y el output o la acción la puedes definir en la misma función. Desconozco cómo lo hace bootstrap en ese sentido, pero es posible

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias!!